# can I add shortcut for 'Open file' button in vscode at top right corner

Tags: visual-studio-code

This button can open setting.json when in setting page, and can open target file when in git diff page. But how can I assign a shortcut to this function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should try `cmd`+`,`

Comment: there is a command attached to these buttons that can be called by the command palette or a keybinding, go to keybindings and search for `open settings`

Comment: ok. It seems that this icon has different commands in different place. So I have to assign multiple shortucts, right?

Comment: It doesn't look like that's a control that's available through the command palette, which means there's no way to assign it to a keyboard shortcut. It's definitely worth a feature request though IMO

Answer (score -1):

You can find it under

[GitLens: Open File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evBBJ.png)

As the icon, the command appears only when you have a diff editor open.

Comment: That isn't the same option though - GitLens is a separate extension, which isn't the one that provides this command.

Comment: Well at least it works the same way as the icon and you can assign a shortcut to it :-)

Comment: I can't find that command. What is the commandId? @AronBe

Comment: commandId: `gitlens.openWorkingFile`